# Null condition checking in report for float

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *iReport* designer for designing report. Here data type of column data is real. In report corresponding data type is Float.

If the float value is empty or null i need to display that as a blank value.

The *textField's* attribute expression `isBlankWhenNull="true"`  is not working for Float

Here is my code

```xml
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="342" y="314" width="78" height="18"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Float"><![CDATA[$F{ws1}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

I'm using *iReport 3.7.6*.

The result of my report is:

[image]

The cells with 0.0 should be blank.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: i want the code for float value is empty or null i need to display that as a blank value.

Comment: What version of *JasperReports (iReport)* are you using?

Comment: The expression `<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">` works well for *java.lang.Float*. Can you post the values from your datasource and the screenshot of the result?

Comment: i'll do that tomorrow thanx :)

Comment: i'm using ireport 3.7.6
here is the screenshot (0.0 should be blank thats what i want)  
[link](http://i39.tinypic.com/2ih46sp.jpg)

Comment: Try this `<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[($F{ws1} == 0.0) ? null : $F{ws1}]]></textFieldExpression>` additionally to `<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">`